# Are non-Googleable list-like questions allowed?

Tags: discussion, scope

Sorry if this is a dupe:

I would like to ask "Are there any other scifi novels with ADHD-diagnosed characters other than Percy Jackson?"

I have spent quite a while Googling and have come up with only one quasi-sci-fi book - Playing Tyler. As such, having found no valid answer via Google, I'd like to ask the question here. Yet, I'm aware that list-like questions are rarely encouraged, if not outright banned. Would this be an acceptable question as it stands now to ask?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the [FAQ](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

> *Not all questions have a home on Stack Exchange. **Please note the
>   following types of questions are off-topic here:***
>
> ***Questions calling for a list of works, authors, …: What are all the
>   books that have X?***

Although you've played with the wording, your question is still a request for recommendations (which are off-topic).